# Linker failing to find existing static library with correct name

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, mingw-w64

I am currently writing a small test application to explore statically linking libraries and accessing their symbols at runtime with Boost.DLL. I am attempting to compile a very simple static library and link it with a very simple application, using MinGW-w64, and am doing this with a Makefile and `mingw32-make`.

The following is the Makefile:

```
B_INCLUDE_PATH = -IC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/

INCLUDE_PATH = -IC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/
LIB_PATH = -LC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib -L.
LIBS = -llibboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-x64-1_78 -llibboost_system-mgw8-mt-x64-1_78
SRCS = main.cpp A.cpp
OUT = out

#build executable
out:
    g++ -c -Wall ${B_INCLUDE_PATH} B.cpp -o B.o
    ar -rcs -o libB.lib B.o
    g++ -Wall ${INCLUDE_PATH} ${LIB_PATH} ${SRCS} ${LIBS} -Wl,-Bstatic -lB -o ${OUT}

#build and run executable
run: out
    ./out
```

The following is the command prompt output:

```
C:\Unix\VSC\Derive_Test>mingw32-make
g++ -c -Wall -IC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/ B.cpp -o B.o
ar -rcs -o libB.lib B.o
g++ -Wall -IC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/ -LC:/Unix/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib -L. main.cpp A.cpp -llibboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-x64-1_78 -llibboost_system-mgw8-mt-x64-1_78 -Wl,-Bstatic -lB -o out
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lB
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:13: out] Error 1
```

I have tried renaming the output file from `ar` with and without the prefix `lib`, and with the suffixes `.a`, `.lib`, and `.so`, with no success.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `-lB` corresponds with `libB.so` , you need to change the library's name

Comment: I tried that; it didn't work. I receive the same error.

Comment: lets try this ` -L.` side by `-lB` => `-L. -lB`

Comment: Yet again the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the command calls to g++ (last line in `out` target) with this:

```
g++ -Wall ${INCLUDE_PATH} ${LIB_PATH} ${SRCS} ${LIBS} -c -o main.o
g++ B.o main.o -o ${OUT}
```

Comment: This causes the error ``g++: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files``. This suggestion would require that I turn all my source files into intermediate object files and link them; this is something I'd like to avoid. I would rather compile object files for the "plugin" modules into a single library that can be linked with the complete program.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to compile; it seemed to be that `ld` on MinGW-w64 was looking for the specific name `lib<library name>.a`. I must have neglected this specific combination of prefix and suffix. Thanks for the responses.